# laravel Process could not be started [Le chemin d'acc�s sp�cifi� est introuvable. when send mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I use flutter for developement mobile application and in backend I use laravel, now when I try to register user then send mail I found this error in send mail.

> Process could not be started [Le chemin d'acc�s sp�cifi� est introuvable.

code .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER= smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
    MAIL_PORT=465
    MAIL_USERNAME=my gmail
    MAIL_PASSWORD=my password
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=my gmail
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

code mail.php:

```
         'mailers' => [
            'smtp' => [
                'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
                'transport' => 'mail',
                'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.googlemail.org'),
                'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
                'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
                'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
                'timeout' => null,
                'auth_mode' => null,
            ],

            'ses' => [
                'transport' => 'ses',
            ],

            'mailgun' => [
                'transport' => 'mailgun',
            ],

            'postmark' => [
                'transport' => 'postmark',
            ],

            'sendmail' => [
                'transport' => 'sendmail',
                'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
            ],

            'log' => [
                'transport' => 'log',
                'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
            ],

            'array' => [
                'transport' => 'array',
            ],
        ],
```

how to resolve this error and thanks.

Comment: did you run php artisan config:cache and php artisan config:clear ?

Answer (score 0):

if someone has such error in the the future i fixed it that way :
go to the file vendor\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php and comment out the code $options = []; and paste the code $options['ssl'] = array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true);